# How to access buckets when retention policy is persistent?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I have 3 forge viewers that I use, I have no access to buckets from particularly in one viewer. Only difference of this viewer is retention policy: persistent.

When I want to delete or see details an object from a bucket first I get a 2-Legged Token

```
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate'
  -X 'POST'
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  -d '
    client_id=...&
    client_secret=...&
    grant_type=client_credentials& 
scope=bucket:create%20bucket:read%20bucket:delete%20data:write%20data:read%20account:read%20viewables:read'
```

and then use this token in

```
curl -v "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/apptestbucket/objects?limit=1"
  -X GET
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ..."
  -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

but when this last call is made, I only recieve

```
* Connection #0 to host developer.api.autodesk.com left intact
{"reason":"No access"}
```

Can it be because of retention policy or do I miss something ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rention policy will not affect your access/permission to a bucket and there're pretty much only two things that would which are whether your Forge app is granted access (owner or authorized via bucket permissions) and the scope of your token.

To view, update or delete a bucket object make sure your token is given the scopes below:

```
GET bucket(s)/details - bucket:read
GET object(s) - data:read
DELETE object - data:write
PUT object data:write
```

And to determine whether your current client credentials have access to a bucket use [GET buckets](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-GET/) to list all your buckets:

```
{
  "items" : [ {
    "bucketKey" : "00001fbf-8505-49ab-8a42-44c6a96adbd0",
    "createdDate" : 1441329298362,
    "policyKey" : "transient"
  }, {
    "bucketKey" : "0003114d",
    "createdDate" : 1440119769765,
    "policyKey" : "transient"
  }, {
    "bucketKey" : "0003fbc1-389a-4194-915a-38313797d753",
    "createdDate" : 1453886285506,
    "policyKey" : "transient"
  }, {
...
```

Comment: When I saw the list of my all buckets, I have found the problem. In the front of my bucket names there is always 32 digit numeral and alphabetical string. So all my bucket names are unknown_string + '-' + mybucket_name. Why can it be ?

Comment: you must have used one of our starter (learnForge) samples to create the bucket ... a prefix would be added to the buckets created using those samples so ppl getting started with Forge and OSS won’t run into naming conflicts since bucket names have to be globally unique (tends to get ignored no matter how much you stress) ... create the bucket with POST bucket endpoint and you get to name them freely. honestly i am not a fan of that approach as it’d lead to more confusion like what you are experiencing now but i’d defer to our mighty leadership for their good sense...

Comment: Alright now everything makes sense, the only thing is, I guess that in earlier stages of this tutorial there was no prefix addition on creation of buckets. Thank you very much for the information.